# Quand l'adjectif verbal est-il différent du participe présent ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, adjectifs, participe-présent

Il y a pléthore de participes présents qui changent de forme quand ils sont employés comme adjectifs verbaux. E.g.,

> adhérer   adhérant    adhérent
>
> coïncider coïncidant  coïncident
>
> confluer  confluant   confluent
>
> converger convergeant convergent
>
> différer  différant   différent
>
> diverger  divergeant  divergent
>
> équivaloir    équivalant  équivalent
>
> négliger  négligeant  négligent

etc. ([Référence](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/adjectif-verbal-et-participe-present-94.php))

Faut-il que l'on apprenne par cœur ces cas particuliers ou y a-t-il un mécanisme qui explique la différence ? De plus, y a-t-il une règle mnémonique ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense qu'il faut surtout apprendre ces listes d'exceptions, plus ou moins complètes (http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison32.htm)

Ce qui est notable concernant certains mots de cette liste (https://www.agirenfrancais.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/adjectif-verbal.pdf?x60889), c'est que la fin de l'adjectif verbal est construite de façon semblable au nom correspondant, par exemple :

différer (infinitif) | différ**ant** (participe présent) | différ**ent** (adjectif verbal) | différ**ence** (nom)

Pour tous les adjectifs en -ent dans la question, il y a un nom correspondant en -ence. Ce test ne marche pas à tous les coups, par exemple il y a un nom *correspondance*.